# How to sort a List of Arrays that contains sorted Arrays?

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, list, sorting

I Have a `List(Of Integer())` where the integer arrays contains sorted elements but the elements of the list aren't sorted, example:

```
MyList(0) = {1, 35, 39, 42}
MyList(1) = {1, 5, 9, 12}
MyList(2) = {6, 8, 19, 62}
```

How I could sort the list index basing me in the order of the Arrays to produce this?:

```
MyList(0) = {1, 5, 9, 12}
MyList(2) = {1, 35, 39, 42}
MyList(1) = {6, 8, 19, 62}
```

I was trying to evaluate only the first element of each Array but of course this not produce the desired result 'cause is not evaluating the rest values:

```
MyList = (From arr As Integer() In MyList Order By arr.First Ascending).ToList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a supplement to LB's answer, one can create a more generic array comparer like this:

```
Public Class ArrayComparer(Of T As IComparable)
    Implements IComparer(Of T())

    Public Function Compare(x() As T, y() As T) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of T()).Compare
        Dim i, n As Integer
        For i = 0 To (Math.Min(x.Count, y.Count) - 1)
            n = x(i).CompareTo(y(i))
            If (n <> 0) Then Return n
        Next
        Return x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length)
    End Function

End Class
```

Now, given the following list:

```
Dim list As New List(Of Integer())

For i As Integer = 1 To 2
    For j As Integer = 1 To 2
        For k As Integer = 1 To 2
            For l As Integer = 1 To 2
                list.Add(New Integer() {i, j, k, l})
            Next
            list.Add(New Integer() {i, j, k})
        Next
        list.Add(New Integer() {i, j})
    Next
    list.Add(New Integer() {i})
Next
```

And the following action:

```
list = list.OrderBy((Function(a As Integer()) a), New ArrayComparer(Of Integer)).ToList()
```

The result looks like this:

```
1
1,1
1,1,1
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,2
1,1,2
1,1,2,1
1,1,2,2
1,2
1,2,1
1,2,1,1
1,2,1,2
1,2,2
1,2,2,1
1,2,2,2
2
2,1
2,1,1
2,1,1,1
2,1,1,2
2,1,2
2,1,2,1
2,1,2,2
2,2
2,2,1
2,2,1,1
2,2,1,2
2,2,2
2,2,2,1
2,2,2,2
```

If preferable, add a secondary sort expression to include the length.

```
list = list.OrderBy((Function(a As Integer()) a), New ArrayComparer(Of Integer)).ThenBy(Function(a As Integer()) a.Length).ToList()
```

Result:

```
1
2
1,1
1,2
2,1
2,2
1,1,1
1,1,2
1,2,1
1,2,2
2,1,1
2,1,2
2,2,1
2,2,2
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,2
1,1,2,1
1,1,2,2
1,2,1,1
1,2,1,2
1,2,2,1
1,2,2,2
2,1,1,1
2,1,1,2
2,1,2,1
2,1,2,2
2,2,1,1
2,2,1,2
2,2,2,1
2,2,2,2
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a c# answer

```
class ListComparer : IComparer<List<int>>
{
    public int Compare(List<int> x, List<int> y)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(x.Count, y.Count); i++)
        {
            if (x[i] != y[i]) return x[i] - y[i];
        }
        return x.Count - y.Count;
    }
}
```

---

```
var newList = MyList.OrderBy(l => l, new ListComparer()).ToList();
```

**EDIT: @ElektroStudios,** this will be my first VB code:

I used the site you mentioned in comments , made a few changes and this is what I got

```
Dim MyList As New List(Of List(Of Integer))

MyList.Add(New List(Of Integer) From {1, 35, 39, 42})
MyList.Add(New List(Of Integer) From {1, 5, 9, 12})
MyList.Add(New List(Of Integer) From {6, 8, 19, 62})


Dim newList = MyList.OrderBy(Function(l) l, New ListComparer()).ToList()
```

---

```
Public Class ListComparer
Implements IComparer(Of List(Of Integer))

Public Function Compare1(x As List(Of Integer), y As List(Of Integer)) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of List(Of Integer)).Compare
    For i As Integer = 0 To Math.Min(x.Count, y.Count) - 1
        If x(i) <> y(i) Then
            Return x(i) - y(i)
        End If
    Next
    Return x.Count - y.Count
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: It throws me an exception with my translation `Dim newList = mylist.OrderBy(Function(l As Integer) l, New ListComparer()).ToList()` with this message: `Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) in extension method 'Public Function OrderBy(Of TKey)(keySelector As System.Func(Of Integer(), TKey), comparer As System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of TKey)) As System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable(Of Integer())' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable' cannot be inferred from these arguments because they do not convert to the same type. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.`

Comment: Note: I've just used http://converter.telerik.com/ to translate the code that you've provided me, without any own changes, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at merge sort. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort has the details